# What does this statement do exactly

Tags: c#, if-statement, datatable

```
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            this.Hide();

            Game GG = new Game();
            GG.Show();
        }
        else // else it will display this error
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct login details");
        }
    }
```

This is an if statement I am using for my game I am creating in c#. I'm trying to write internal commentary so I can describe each function properly and have a better understanding of the language. any help would be appreciated, Its just the top line i'm unsure about.

Comment: You wrote it so shoudnt you know what it does? Eiither way, it's checking to see if the First element of the First element of Rows has a value in a string of 1

Comment: Given the tag, you apparently know that `dt` is a datatable. Finding its documentation on MSDN shouldn't be rocket science for a game builder..

Comment: @Toxicable I'm just learning its from a video where a guy shows how to make a login system with a database connection. thanks either way tho

Comment: @GolezTrol No it isn't rocket science but I'm very new to programming and unsure about a lot of c# contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
```

The first [0] is the row index and the second [0] is the column index.

So in pseudo code:

```
if (the value of the first row in the first column == "1")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah I get you, I was just having trouble finding a decent description but I feel you now, THanks man

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.